# jmeter throwing “Empty TestPlan - see log file” while opening a test plan

Tags: jmeter

Good day, you try to open a file testplan get the error "Empty TestPlan - see log file"

***jmeter.log***

```
        2014/08/21 11:11:05 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\Users\kislov\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.11\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\examples\ProposalRequest_atom1.jmx 
    2014/08/21 11:11:05 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Users\kislov\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.11\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\examples' 
    2014/08/21 11:11:05 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: -1 : -1
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : -1
    cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    cause-message       : -1
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[9]/hashTree[2]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
    line number         : 948
    class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController
    converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
    class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
    ------------------------------- : -1 : -1
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : -1
    cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    cause-message       : -1
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[9]/hashTree[2]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
    line number         : 948
    class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController
    converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
    class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
    -------------------------------
    message             : -1 : -1
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : -1
    cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    cause-message       : -1
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[9]/hashTree[2]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
    line number         : 948
    class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController
    converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
    class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
    -------------------------------
    cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
    cause-message       : -1 : -1
    first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:107)
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
    required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[9]/hashTree[2]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
    line number         : 948
    version             : 2.11 r1554548
    ------------------------------- 
    2014/08/21 11:11:05 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error org.apache.jmeter.exceptions.IllegalUserActionException: Empty TestPlan - see log file
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:174)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:136)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:105)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:92)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

    2014/08/21 11:11:51 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\Users\kislov\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.11\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\examples\ProposalRequest_atom1.jmx 
    2014/08/21 11:11:51 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Users\kislov\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.11\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\examples' 
    2014/08/21 11:11:51 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: -1 : -1
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : -1
    cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    cause-message       : -1
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[9]/hashTree[2]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
    line number         : 948
    class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController
    converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
    class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
    ------------------------------- : -1 : -1
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : -1
    cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    cause-message       : -1
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[9]/hashTree[2]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
    line number         : 948
    class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController
    converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
    class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
    -------------------------------
    message             : -1 : -1
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : -1
    cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    cause-message       : -1
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[9]/hashTree[2]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
    line number         : 948
    class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController
    converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
    class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
    -------------------------------
    cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
    cause-message       : -1 : -1
    first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:107)
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
    required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[9]/hashTree[2]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
    line number         : 948
    version             : 2.11 r1554548
    ------------------------------- 
    2014/08/21 11:11:51 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error org.apache.jmeter.exceptions.IllegalUserActionException: Empty TestPlan - see log file
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:174)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:136)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:105)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:92)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

    2014/08/21 11:20:32 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\Users\kislov\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.11\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\examples\ProposalRequest_atom1.jmx 
    2014/08/21 11:20:32 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Users\kislov\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.11\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\examples' 
    2014/08/21 11:20:32 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: -1 : -1
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : -1
    cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    cause-message       : -1
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[9]/hashTree[2]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
    line number         : 948
    class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController
    converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
    class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
    ------------------------------- : -1 : -1
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : -1
    cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    cause-message       : -1
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[9]/hashTree[2]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
    line number         : 948
    class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController
    converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
    class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
    -------------------------------
    message             : -1 : -1
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : -1
    cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    cause-message       : -1
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[9]/hashTree[2]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
    line number         : 948
    class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController
    converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
    class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
    -------------------------------
    cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
    cause-message       : -1 : -1
    first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:107)
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
    required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
    converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[9]/hashTree[2]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
    line number         : 948
    version             : 2.11 r1554548
    ------------------------------- 
    2014/08/21 11:20:32 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error org.apache.jmeter.exceptions.IllegalUserActionException: Empty TestPlan - see log file
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:174)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:136)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:105)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:92)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Any feedback on answer, if ok you should accept it and upvote

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above, jMeter 2.11 is not compatible with Java 8. The easiest fix will be changing the java.exe path in jmeter.bat to Java 7 :

Change the below settings in jmeter.bat (apache-jmeter-2.11\bin)

```
if .%JM_LAUNCH% == . set JM_LAUNCH=java.exe
```

to

```
if .%JM_LAUNCH% == . set JM_LAUNCH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre\bin\java.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check:

1/ You are not using it with java 8 ( it is not compatible, next version 2.12 will be). Run java -version in command line to see. Bug is the following:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56080

2/ your test plan is not using third party plugins you need to add in lib/ext of jmeter

Comment: Actually, JMeter 2.11 can't be used with Java 8, you'll need to downgrade to Java 7. I went to 7.0.67, and it worked fine.